# Java : Issue with Object Cloning?

Tags: java, clone

I have `invoice` object and it has two properties, `productDescription` and `productQuantity`, here is the code:

```java
public class Invoice() implements Cloneable
{
  private String productDescription;
  private int productQuantity;

  //Getters & Setters

  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
     return super.clone();
  }
}
```

Now i want to create copy of object on this class so am doing

```java
Invoice invoiceCopy = (Invoice)invoice.clone();
```

Now if i update value of `invoiceCopy.setProductQuanity = 10` then `invoice` also updates the value but that should not happen, any suggestions?

### **Updated Code**

```java
public class Invoice implements Cloneable {
    private String productDescritpion;
    private int productQuantity;

    public String getProductDescritpion() {
        return productDescritpion;
    }

    public void setProductDescritpion(String productDescritpion) {
        this.productDescritpion = productDescritpion;
    }

    public int getProductQuantity() {
        return productQuantity;
    }

    public void setProductQuantity(int i) {
        this.productQuantity = i;
    }

    public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
        return super.clone();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
        invoice.setProductQuantity(10);
        invoice.setProductDescritpion("nike");
        Invoice invoiceCopy = null;
        try {
            invoiceCopy = (Invoice) invoice.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        invoiceCopy.setProductQuantity(20);
        System.out.println("Invoice quantity: " + invoice.getProductQuantity());
        System.out.println("InvoiceCopy quantity: "
                + invoiceCopy.getProductQuantity());
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: am confused with `clone` behaviour, i thought if i try to update my cloned object then it would also update property of object from which object was cloned but ran simple example above and it contradicts my assumption

Comment: Your code works exactly as expected for object cloning. Clone creates a copy of the object so it is effectively a new instance. As the fields of your object are an immutable String and a primitive there are no references between the original object and the clone. Hence changes to the clone are not seen in the original object.

Comment: @Mark: Example i have here is just the representation of actual code, right now issue i have is where if property of cloned object is changed then this difference is reflected in the object from which clone was created too, debugging issue right now to figure out what is going on...

Comment: @Rachel: Then I suggest you find an example which actually demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [Java's clone() is a bad idea](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=71), I suggest you use a copy constructor instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

default clone methode is a superficial one.
you have to write yourself a new method or use a library that does what you want (see apache's BeanUtils for exemple)

if you want to write it, try something like :

```
public class Invoice implements Cloneable {
private String productDescription;
private int productQuantity;

public Invoice() {
}

public Invoice(Invoice copy) {
    productDescription = copy.productDescription;
    productQuantity = copy.productQuantity;
}

public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
    return new Invoice(this);
}
```

}

Comment: The default clone method should do fine here - it will do the equivalent of your constructor anyway (except it will ensure it's actually the right type).

Comment: @mabroukb this is a terrible answer. not only is the default clone implementation going to do the same thing, you will also break any potential subclasses that will implement clone. I don't downvote, but you surely deserve one here

Answer (score -1):

You are just calling the `clone()` method of `Object` which will do nothing for your class. you need to return a new instance of your object:

```
public class Invoice() implements Cloneable {
  private String productDescription;
  private int productQuantity;

  public Invoice() {

  }

  private Invoice(String productDescription, int productQuantity) {
    this.productDescription = productDescription; 
    this.productQuantity = productQuantity;

  //Getters & Setters

  public Object clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException {
     return new Invoice(productDescription, productQuantity);
  }
}
```

I added constructors to pass the arguments.

Comment: The default implementation of `clone()` does exactly the right thing when all that's needed is a shallow copy (as is the case here).

Comment: This will fix the issue so I see no problem here. If you use `Object.clone()` and use references to mutable objects you could run into a lot of trouble.

Comment: But neither a String or int are mutable objects so the default clone() method will work correctly.

Comment: That's right but think about modifiability. Once you implemented it that way and trusting it while adding a new field, it is possible that you get into issues. I do not see any advantage.

Comment: @Stephan: But that's entirely separate from this question. Your code does not change anything about what will happen for the code given.

Comment: ...assuming the given code is complete, which I do not think.

Comment: @Stephan one advantage of calling super.clone() is that it ensure the cloned object has the correct type. With you implementation if we added a subclass of Invoice any call to super.clone would return the wrong type.

Comment: @Stephan: Yes, there's something else going on here - but your code *as it stands* does not help the class *as it stands*. And anyone writing a *shallow* copy via a constructor would run into exactly the same problems if it turns out there's a mutable object "embedded" within the real code.